# Sentiment analysis for sentences with overall positive sentiment but have negative words

Tags: sentiment-analysis, nlp

I am trying to work on a sentiment analysis tool for reviews data. I came across a few edge-cases where the overall sentiment of a sentence may be positive but contain a negative word.  
For example :

> I want this iPad so bad. 
>   F*ck yes, it looks good!

I tried 2-3 sentiment analyzing libraries and they infer such sentences with negative sentiment. I have not found any work which is looking into such solutions. 
Is there any known solution to handle sentiment in such contextual cases?

I tried mostly lexicon based approaches. I used NLTK, SPACY, [IBM tone analyzer](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/tone-analyzer/), TextBlob, VADER. Currently I am averaging the summation of results from all of them.

Comment: What library did you use? What have you tried so far? please edit your question and give more details.

Comment: I tried mostly lexicon based approaches. I used NLTK, SPACY, TextBlob, VADER. Currently, I am averaging the summation of results from all of them.

Comment: How prevalent are these edge cases? Could you live with a few false negatives? I would imagine this is an active area of sentiment analysis research. Have you tried looking through Google Scholar or arxiv?

Comment: tried looking, did not find any strong relevant work- I may take a stab at it. Thanks for the input.